# What does Team Site have to do with SharePoint?

Tags: sharepoint-foundation

What does Team Site have to do with SharePoint? I'm new as you know. I'm watching a video on SharePoint and they mentioned that Team Site is a template for SharePoint.

Answer (score 2):

Team Site is one of main collaboration templates in SharePoint. You can use this site template to create libraries, lists, discussion boards etc.

The Team site can be used as a single environment to create, organize, and share content. For example, use the Announcements list to broadcast key information, new tools, or resources to team members. Use the Calendar to share scheduling information, like team events, deadlines, or vacations. You might also try the Links list to help your team connect with partner sites or find key information for their jobs. [1](https://support.office.com/en-gb/article/Using-templates-to-create-different-kinds-of-SharePoint-sites-449eccec-ff99-4cf3-b62e-dcfee37e8da4)

More on the basics of a Team site [here](http://www.boostsolutions.com/blog/understanding-basics-team-site-sharepoint-2013-office-365/)

[1](https://support.office.com/en-gb/article/Using-templates-to-create-different-kinds-of-SharePoint-sites-449eccec-ff99-4cf3-b62e-dcfee37e8da4) - [office.com](https://support.office.com/en-gb/article/Using-templates-to-create-different-kinds-of-SharePoint-sites-449eccec-ff99-4cf3-b62e-dcfee37e8da4)

Comment: I apologize if my question is a bit ignorant.  Am I correct in that TeamSite is NOT a separate application that holds SharePoint. It is the first empty hierarchy within SharePoint that enables me to create sub-sites for users?

Comment: That's correct in a way. Your root site might be based on a team site template, but it can be based on a different template as well. Your subsites can be team sites OR they can based on other templates. Team Site is a template that comes with some default resources (lists, libraries, etc.) it can be applied to any site in SharePoint - doesn't matter if it's a root site, or a subsite.

Answer (score 2):

Here is a link to a basic overview of a team site: https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Learn-your-way-around-a-team-site-fa23e109-5a54-4c0b-91e6-e87a1434e65c

Key Points:

- A team site is an internal website where your team can share
  information.
- All team sites come with certain elements, such as a
  Documents library where you can upload, share, view, edit, and
  collaborate on files like Word documents, Excel workbooks, and
  PowerPoint presentations.
- Your team site is a place where you and
  your teammates share files and information.

Comment: So, in other words, the Teamsite is the first empty site within SharePoint 13 that allows the SharePoint administrator to create sub-sites for SharePoint users? Is this correct?